# Input not showing text as typing in mobile

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile

On mobile devices, when you tap on a field that is empty and begin to type, what you type doesn't show until you move onto the next field. This is only on mobile devices, and doesn't happen when you simulate in browser.

Can anyone help with this?

http://crosbiedesign.us2.list-manage.com/profile?u=40578a599677f3c227f54a7c8&id=b276fd7f25&e=a7abae536e

This is the CSS for the inputs...

```
.input {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0em;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.input__field {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 0.8em;
    width: 60%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: bolder;
    letter-spacing:0.02em;
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* for box shadows to show on iOS */
}

.input__field:focus {
    outline: transparent;
}

.input__label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: 40%;
    color: #6a7989;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 80%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.input__label-content {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.input--shoko {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

.input__field--shoko {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0.8em;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.55em;
}

.input__label--shoko {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.1s, color 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.2s 0.1s, color 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.graphic--shoko {
    stroke: #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    top: 1.25em;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 3.275em;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.7s, stroke 0.7s;
    transition: transform 0.7s, stroke 0.7s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1);
} 

.input__field--shoko:focus + .input__label--shoko,
.input--filled .input__label--shoko {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 3.5em, 0) scale3d(0.85, 0.85, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0, 3.5em, 0) scale3d(0.85, 0.85, 1);
}

.input__field--shoko:focus ~ .graphic--shoko,
.input--filled .graphic--shoko {
    stroke: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-66.6%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-66.6%, 0, 0);
}
input, input:before, input:after {
    -webkit-user-select: initial;
    -khtml-user-select: initial;
    -moz-user-select: initial;
    -ms-user-select: initial;
    user-select: initial;
   }
```

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make sure we can help you, please help us a little by adding your code to the question.

Comment: Just added the CSS

Comment: Any tips on this? Would really appreciate it. Cheers, Michael